# Vue v-for not update model variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i try to render page with dynamic properties. my code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="current in 2" :key="current">
    <p :style="currentObject.color">
      {{ current  }}
      {{ currentObject.text }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

script is

```
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  created: function () {
  console.log(this.current)
  },
  data : {
    current : 0,
    arrs : [
      {
        color : "background-color: blue;",
        text : "Dabodee Dabodai"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: red;",
        text : "Angry"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: green;",
        text : "See it works!"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed : {
    currentObject : function() {
      return this.arrs[this.current];
    }
  }
});
```

i want to p tag with different color and container object text via currentObject but when render the page, computed act likes current is 0 always. output is blue and text from currentObject is "Dabodee Dabodai"

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed property is not the best option here as it will get calculated whenever it changes, meaning that if you iterate through an array the computed value will change on every iteration and at the end you will have all instances with the same value:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

What you want is to iterate through your array or access the desired location; so the the most simple approach will work here. As someone already state the for loop will start at 1 so you want to do a -1 to start from the first array location:

```
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="current in 3" :key="current">
    <p :style="arrs[current-1].color">
      {{ current  }}
      {{ arrs[current-1].text }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If per the update you want to keep it reactive you can track changes on the arrs value and take an action using a watch to refresh certain item when the array is updated

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the v-for

v-for loops through an array
and in javascript syntax in is used to loop through an array

```js
let arrs = [
      {
        color : "background-color: blue;",
        text : "Dabodee Dabodai"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: red;",
        text : "Angry"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: green;",
        text : "See it works!"
      }
    ]
for(i in arrs){
console.log(arrs[i])
}
```

**Corrected code**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="current in arrs" :key="current">
    <p :style="currentObject.color">
      {{ current  }}
      {{ currentObject.text }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

after this modification this above snippet should work

Comment: Vue v-for can work as iterator, if you pass number

Comment: your code's output is

{ "color": "background-color: blue;", "text": "Dabodee Dabodai" } Dabodee Dabodai

{ "color": "background-color: red;", "text": "Angry" } Dabodee Dabodai

{ "color": "background-color: green;", "text": "See it works!" } Dabodee Dabodai

in color blue and i'm try to trigger computed with current variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your v-for variable name is wrong, you already have `current` in `data`, also computed property is not attached to v-for loop, here is working example:

Template:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js></script>
<div id="root">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in arrs" :key="index">
        <p :style="{ backgroundColor: item.color }">
            {{ index  }}
            {{ item.text }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and Vue code:

```
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  data : {
    arrs : [
      {
        color : "blue",
        text : "Dabodee Dabodai"
      },
      {
        color : "red",
        text : "Angry"
      },
      {
        color : "green",
        text : "See it works!"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but my other goal is when i change the property array, want to change p property so i need computed as well.

Comment: @ÇağlarBingöl Array is also reactive, so u don't need computed. template will be updated automatically. Or if you want render only one property, you don't need v-for, just use computed

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that in your case the computed Property `currentObject` is accesible in the complete Vue instance. `this.current` is `0` and doesn't get updated, so `currentObject` always returns the same value.

If you really want to access the properties throught the `v-for` loop, with `in 2` you must keep in mind the loop will always starts with 1.

The best practice would be to loop the array with `(current, index) in arrs`

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  data : {
    arrs : [
      {
        color : "background-color: blue;",
        text : "Dabodee Dabodai"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: red;",
        text : "Angry"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: green;",
        text : "See it works!"
      }
    ]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="(current, index) in arrs" :key="index">
    <p :style="current.color">
      {{ current.text }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have other goal to when i change array object, i want to change property as well. your code will work but not complate my goal.

Comment: So you want to make a dynamic form or what?

Comment: yes i want to dynamic form for example think that i have a button that changes arr[0].color i want to p in that color

Comment: @ÇağlarBingöl Okay, you'll change `current`, computed will update props, but remove v-for, it shouldn't be here. Computed will do all the work